# ghostscript write command windows

Tags: ghostscript

I've installed ghostscript on Windows 7.

I want to test, how it can compress pdf files.

I've opened application, and i have window with command line.

How to write commangs in GS ? I was trying `gs -h`, but i have error.

I found on web:

```
Unix        gs
VMS         gs
DOS & MS Windows 3      gs386
MS Windows 95/98        gswin32
MS Windows 95/98 command line       gswin32c
OS/2        gsos2
```

but i have windows 7 64 bit :)

Thanks for help.

**EDIT**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ghostscript on all platforms accepts the same set of command line arguments. If you are on Windows then you need either gswin32, gswin32c, gswin64 or gswin64c. Trying to run 'gs' on Windows won't work because that's not what the executable is called.....

When you run the console ('c') versions of Ghostscript you enter into an interactive PostScript session, unless you are a PostScript programmer you won't want that.

You need to open a Windows shell, navigate to where Ghostscript is installed (c:/Program Files (x86)/gs or c:/Program Files/gs depending on 32 or 64 bit) and then run it from there. Documentation can be found at the Ghostscript [web site](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.15/Readme.htm).

Ghostscript does *NOT* compress PDF files. By using the pdfwrite device you can create a new PDF file which *may* be smaller than the original, depending on the options you select, but its not the same PDF file compressed, its a brand new one.

Comment: ok, i was trying with gswin64 -h and have still this same Error:

Comment: You can't type 'gswin64c' at the Ghostscript command prompt, that *is* gswin64c.exe. When you start the executable with no command line paramters what you get is an interactive PostScript environment. Since 'gswin64c' isn't a valid PostScript program, it fails, unsurprisingly. You need to open a command shell and start gswin64c from there, along with appropriate command line controls. See the documentation in the answer above.  Of course, you *can* type valid PostScript at the command prompt, but I very much doubt you want to try and do that.